# multiple event targets on same parent element not working

Tags: javascript, django, dom-events

I have been dealing with this problem for quite some time. It's been a great way to learn Javascript, but I'm just done and need help before I end up in prison for something. I need the inline formset's delete checkbox checked before removing the parent element (form). I am using Django's inline formsets and am currently refusing to use jquery to handle this because I want to learn good ol' vanilla Javascript. The onclick will do one or the other. Won't do both in the same click of the button. I have tried all things to handle bubbling and capturing to the best of my ability. Okay I'll be quiet now.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/availability_update_new.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<form id="all-add-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <legend class="bottom mb-4">Profiles Info</legend>
    {{ sun_bool.sunday|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ sunday_formset.management_form }}
    {% for sun_form in sunday_formset %}
        {% for hidden in sun_form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="sun_time_slot_form">
            {{ sun_form }}
            <button class="delete-sun-form" type="button" id="delete-sun-btn" onclick="one();"> Delete This Sunday
                Timeslot
            </button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button id="add-sun-form" type="button" class="button">Add Other Sunday Times</button>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/add_timeslot.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
{% endblock content %}



const sunForm = document.getElementsByClassName('sun_time_slot_form');
const mainForm = document.querySelector('#all-add-form');
const addSunBtn = document.querySelector("#add-sun-form");
const submitFormBtn = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
const totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_id_sunday_formset-TOTAL_FORMS");

let formCount = sunForm.length - 1;

addSunBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newSunForm = sunForm[0].cloneNode(true);
    const formRegex = RegExp(`id_sunday_formset-(\\d){1}-`, 'g');

    formCount++;

    newSunForm.innerHTML = newSunForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, 
    `id_sunday_formset-${formCount}-`);
    mainForm.insertBefore(newSunForm, submitFormBtn);
    totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formCount + 1}`);
});

function updateSunForm() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let sun_form of sunForm) {
        const sunFormRegex = RegExp(`id_sunday_formset-(\\d){1}-`, 'g');
        sun_form.innerHTML = sun_form.innerHTML.replace(sunFormRegex, 
            `id_sunday_formset-${count++}-`)
    }
}

mainForm.addEventListener('click', (ee) => {
    if (ee.target.classList.contains('delete-sun-form')) {
        ee.preventDefault();
        ee.target.value;
        ee.target.parentElement.querySelector('input[id$="-DELETE"]' +
            '[type="checkbox"]').checked = true;
        ee.target.value;
        ee.target.parentElement.remove();
        formCount--;
        updateSunForm();
        totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formCount + 1}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you want it to do both? It checks the box but then deletes it, so there isn't a checkbox anymore. The Django formset will only remove the form instance if it finds a checked delete checkbox, so you instead need to hide it once the checkbox is updated.

Comment: My mind did not go there. Thanks for the reasoning! As a beginner, I will scoop my brains off my desk, put them back and get back to work.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! I did the exact same thing when I first used formsets